# frontend workflow (Grunt) meet php backend (Symfony2-Twig)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, workflow, gruntjs

I'm the front-end guy, I use Grunt (cssmin, less compilation, uglify, livereload, image minify, watch, lint...) and I started working with a back-end guy that uses Symfony (twig templating, assetics for most of the task I do with Grunt...)

We are using a sort of Model-View-ViewModel pattern (I'm not back-end expert sorry).

The problem is to find the right workflow for both of us.

I'd like to stay with Grunt since it's the best for front-end right now I think.

My usual workflow is to fire-up Grunt webserver at localhost:9000 and coding with livereload, istant less compilation.

When I'm done I can use "Grunt build" to do the "production" tasks (minify, uglify, image compression...)

The problem comes with Php and Twig templating, I can't use grunt and fire-up a webserver for Php and I can't render the templates with twig.js because it's not what we are using in production.

Also we have to deal with Symfony2 framework server-side.

For the livereloading part I'm using the stand-alone plugin but monitors files and reload the page but for example the less compilation is not working since Lessphp is not fully compatible with Twitter Bootstrap (the framework I'm using on front-end)

Do you have any suggestion? I can add details in case.

I'd prefer to stay with Grunt as much as possible but I can think about using Assetics if he does all the same task or other solution.

This is my actual Gruntfile.js when I work only on front-end:

```
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({
    port: LIVERELOAD_PORT
});
var mountFolder = function(connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

module.exports = function(grunt) {    
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

                src: 'src',
        app: 'app',
        assets: '<%= project.app %>/assets',
        css: [
            '<%= project.src %>/less/bootstrap.less'
        ],
        js: [
            '<%= project.src %>/js/*.js'
        ]
    },

    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            hostname: '*'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function(connect) {
                    return [lrSnippet, mountFolder(connect, 'app')];
                }
            }
        }
    },

    concat: {
        dev: {
            files: {
                '<%= project.assets %>/js/scripts.min.js': '<%= project.js %>'
            }
        },
        options: {
            stripBanners: true,
            nonull: true,
            banner: '<%= tag.banner %>'
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        options: {
            banner: "<%= tag.banner %>"
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= project.assets %>/js/scripts.min.js': '<%= project.js %>'
            }
        }
    },

    less: {
        dev: {
            files: {
                '<%= project.assets %>/css/style.min.css': '<%= project.css %>'
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                cleancss: true
            },
            files: {
                '<%= project.assets %>/css/style.min.css': '<%= project.css %>'
            }
        }
    },

    imagemin: { // Task
        dynamic: { // Another target
            files: [{
                expand: true, // Enable dynamic expansion
                cwd: '<%= project.src %>/img', // Src matches are relative to this path
                src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'], // Actual patterns to match
                dest: '<%= project.assets %>/img' // Destination path prefix
            }]
        }
    },

    open: {
        server: {
            path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
        }
    },

    watch: {
        concat: {
            files: '<%= project.src %>/js/{,*/}*.js',
            tasks: ['concat:dev', 'jshint']
        },
        less: {
            files: '<%= project.src %>/less/{,*/}*.less',
            tasks: ['less:dev']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
            },
            files: [
                '<%= project.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '<%= project.assets %>/css/*.css',
                '<%= project.assets %>/js/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= project.assets %>/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    }
};

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'less:dev',
    'concat:dev',
    'connect:livereload',
    'open',
    'watch'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'less:dist',
    'uglify',
    'imagemin'
]);
```

Comment: could you elaborate where lessphp is not compatible with bootstrap?

Comment: https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/432 
A lot of issue still not resolved, sometimes it works with some build, sometimes it won't so it's definitely not reliable. Also Bootstrap creator stated that they support officially ONLY grunt with cleancss compiler.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn
"Compiling Bootstrap's LESS files
If you work with Bootstrap's uncompiled source code, you need to compile the LESS files to produce usable CSS files. For compiling LESS files into CSS, we only officially support Recess, which is Twitter's CSS hinter based on less.js."

Comment: Thanks for the info , didn't know Bootstrap v3 didn't yet compile correctly with `lessphp`. I'm having problems understanding your exact problem... You are not able to run the symfony project locally and integrate it with an adapted Grunt configuration?

Comment: I'm able to run Symfony2 project on my Ubuntu VM but I don't know how to setup Grunt for monitoring Twig file and reload the page since I use grunt livereload/watch on localhost:9000 usually and it's only plain html not php.

Comment: I have successfully integrated Guard (ruby's task-runner alternative to Grunt) with my symfony2 dev environment in the past. The  livereload server at port 9000 doesn't interfer with symfony2 in any way - it just informs the browser plugin that there is a change for a certain file. If you want to reload if a template has changed just monitor for changes to *.twig files. Could you provide your Grunt configuration? Maybe i can help finding the right regexes for monitoring the symfony folder structure.

Comment: I've added my Gruntfile.js WHEN I WORK on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Using Vagrant the only important thing about reloading is to set watch task on the twig templates.

Here is the `gruntfile.js` edit I made:

```
livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
                },
                files: [
                    ...
                    '<%= project.views %>/{,*/}*.html.twig',
                    '...
                ]
            }
```

Then set a different port on the guest machine:

```
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35728;
```

Then set a forward on your `Vagrantfile` from your guest to your host with the correct port where livereload chrome extension is listening (35729)

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 35728, host: 35729
```

Everything is working like a charm.